# How to change ListboxItem Size with respect to Slider value

Tags: wpf, user-controls, slider, listboxitem

I have two Usercontrols say **"Usercntrl1"** and **"Usercntrl2"**, "Usercntrl1" contains **Slider**, "Usercntr2" has **ListBox with  Images**, Now when i change the **Slider value** in "Usercntrl1" ,the **ListboxItems size(i.e,) Width and Height** has to change with Respect to Slider value. 
It can be easily done when both of them present in same usercontrol as follows

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green"/>
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=sizeSlider, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=sizeSlider, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                         <Setter Property="TabIndex" Value="1"/>
                                           </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

could somebody guide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to bind from one usercontrol to a property of another UserControl maybe you can use something like this:

Usercntrl1:
Xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ListBoxSliderSizeTest.Usercntrl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" x:Name="MainControl">
   <Grid>
      <Slider Maximum="200" Minimum="1" Value="{Binding ElementName=MainControl, Path=SliderSize, Mode=TwoWay}"/>   
   </Grid>
```

CodeBehind:

```
...
public double SliderSize
  {
     get { return (double)GetValue(SliderSizeProperty); }
     set { SetValue(SliderSizeProperty, value); }
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty SliderSizeProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("SliderSize", typeof(double), typeof(Usercntrl1), new PropertyMetadata(0.0));
...
```

UserCntrl2:
XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ListBoxSliderSizeTest.Usercntrl2"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" x:Name="MainControl">
<Grid>
        <ListBox>
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding Path=SliderSize, ElementName=MainControl, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding Path=SliderSize, ElementName=MainControl, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                <Setter Property="TabIndex" Value="1"/>
            </Style>

        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Button/>
        </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

CodeBehind:

```
---
      public double SliderSize
  {
     get { return (double)GetValue(SliderSizeProperty); }
     set { SetValue(SliderSizeProperty, value); }
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty SliderSizeProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("SliderSize", typeof(double), typeof(Usercntrl2), new PropertyMetadata(0.0));
...
```

And then use this two Usercontrols:

```
<listBoxSliderSizeTest:Usercntrl1 x:Name="Usercntrl1"/>
    <listBoxSliderSizeTest:Usercntrl2 Grid.Column="1" SliderSize="{Binding ElementName=Usercntrl1, Path=SliderSize}"/>
```

Edit:

so if Usercntrl1 hosts UserControl2 it looks like this:

Usercntrl1:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Slider Maximum="200" Minimum="1" Value="{Binding ElementName=MainControl, Path=SliderSize, Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="Slider"/>
    <listBoxSliderSizeTest:Usercntrl2 Grid.Row="1" SliderSize="{Binding ElementName=MainControl, Path=SliderSize}" />
</Grid>
```

or:

```
    <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Slider Maximum="200" Minimum="1" x:Name="Slider"/>
    <listBoxSliderSizeTest:Usercntrl2 Grid.Row="1" SliderSize="{Binding ElementName=Slider, Path=Value}" />
</Grid>
```

edit2:

Usercontrol1
XAML:

```
<Slider Maximum="200" Minimum="1" x:Name="Slider" Value="{Binding ElementName=MainControl, Path=SliderSize, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<TabControl x:Name="tc" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

Code behind:

```
var uc = new Usercntrl2();
     var binding = new Binding("SliderSize") { Source = this,Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay};
     uc.SetBinding(Usercntrl2.SliderSizeProperty, binding);
     tc.Items.Add(uc);
```

Comment: thanx a lot, its working perfect in prototype and moreover i have doubt in my scenario, which is **Usercntrl1 as SliderUsrcntrl** hosts **Usercntrl2 as ListboxUsrcntrl**, so i registered the **SliderSize dependency property**, in both the usercntrls now in ListboxUsrcntrl XAML i want to assign the value of **ListboxUsrcntrl Slidersize** as **`ListboxUsrcntrl.SliderSize="{Binding ElementName=Slider Path=SliderSize}"`** i don know where to code like this. thanx in advance.

Comment: I edited my sample. But I'm not sure what your question was in your comment above

Comment: @ rhe ,thanx again and i'm confused with my scenario,actually **Usercntrl1 contains Tabcontrol and Slider where tabitems are loaded dynamically in code behind which is usercntrl2(listbox), usercntrl1 has no reference in XAML as u mentioned above**, so i'm jus stuck with assigning usercntrl2 Slidervalue, sry for nusense. whatever you have given its working perfectly when i do it as prototype. it is like i have to assign **`usecntrl2.SliderSize="{Binding ElementName=usercntrl1, Path=SliderSize}"`** in **usercntrl2XAML** itself, is it so? is this rite way of doin this. thanx again.

Comment: now I'm confused a bit ;-) you want to create the binding in code behind? then the binding looks like in edit2 in my sample. or usercntrl1 does not know the usercntrl2 at all?

Comment: again one small doubt:-) when i change the slider value, listboxitems sizes are getting changed its fine but the prob is it applies to all tabitem, i jus want this to only active tab..

Answer (score 0):

for your question in your last comment (apply the size only to the active item):

use a trigger:

```
 <Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
       <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding Path=SliderSize, ElementName=MainControl, Mode=OneWay}"/>
       <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding Path=SliderSize, ElementName=MainControl, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </DataTrigger>
 </Style.Triggers>
```

or do you want apply it for all items in the active tab?

Comment: no, i need it only for listboxitems, and wat if i want to apply to all items? where do i apply this trigger usercntrl1(TabControl) or usercntrl2(Listbox)? and moreover rite now all tab items contains Listbox with images as listboxitem, andsupppose if i have more controls other than listbox is it possible to apply slidersize value to all items present in present active tab?